# How to set stroke opacity attribute on InkCanvas in UWP

Tags: uwp, inkcanvas

I tried this, without success:

```
  var drawingAttributes = inkCanvas.InkPresenter.CopyDefaultDrawingAttributes();
  drawingAttributes.Color =Color.FromArgb(100,0,0,0);
  inkCanvas.InkPresenter.UpdateDefaultDrawingAttributes(drawingAttributes);
```

The code above changes the color properly but the alpha channel is ignored. I do not want to use the highlighter because its opacity is fixed and one would need to resize it (it is larger than a pen size).

Answer (score 0):

> I do not want to use the highlighter because its opacity is fixed and one would need to resize it (it is larger than a pen size).

There is the [`opacity`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.input.inking.inkdrawingattributespencilproperties#Windows_UI_Input_Inking_InkDrawingAttributesPencilProperties_Opacity) attributes of class [`InkDrawingAttributesPencilProperties`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Input.Inking.InkDrawingAttributesPencilProperties). So you could get or set the level of transparency used for rendering a pencil stroke on an InkCanvas. Please reference the following code.

```
InkDrawingAttributes pencilAttributes = InkDrawingAttributes.CreateForPencil();
pencilAttributes.Color = Windows.UI.Colors.Red;
pencilAttributes.Size = new Windows.Foundation.Size(3, 3);  
pencilAttributes.PencilProperties.Opacity = 0.5f;

// Update InkPresenter with the pencil attributes.

inkCanvas.InkPresenter.UpdateDefaultDrawingAttributes(pencilAttributes);
```

Comment: Thank you, but this does not solve the issue because a pencil is not a pen. I am looking at setting opacity while leaving the stroke filled in full.